# Custom Laravel Passport BearerTokenResponse

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Currently I have a Laravel installation using Laravel Passport (which uses `league/oauth2-server` for the server implementation). I would like to return the user id when a oauth2 token is granted, so I can use it to identify the authenticated user in my EmberJS app.

The suggested method to do this is:

**Create my own class:**

```
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\AccessTokenEntityInterface;

class UserIdBearerTokenResponse extends BearerTokenResponse
{
    protected function getExtraParams(AccessTokenEntityInterface $accessToken)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->accessToken->getUserIdentifier()
        ];
    }
}
```

**Modifying `AuthorizationServer.getResponseType()` in `vendor/league/oauth2-server/src`**

```
protected function getResponseType()
{
    if ($this->responseType instanceof ResponseTypeInterface === false) {
        // Return my own class instead of provided one
        $this->responseType = new UserIdBearerTokenResponse();
    }

    $this->responseType->setPrivateKey($this->privateKey);

    return $this->responseType;
}
```

But this approach requires me to add the `vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php` file to my git repo.

This seems very messy and unreliable to me. Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: What type of token grant is it? How are you generating the token? What does that code look like?

Comment: I think the accepted solution about customization JWT does not sound well.
I would like to make a step configuration without inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use your custom response, you can add a custom authorization server like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\ResponseTypeInterface;

class TokenServer extends AuthorizationServer
{
    /**
     * Get the token type that grants will return in the HTTP response.
     *
     * @return ResponseTypeInterface
     */
    protected function getResponseType()
    {
        if ($this->responseType instanceof ResponseTypeInterface === false) {
            $this->responseType = new UserIdBearerTokenResponse();
        }

        $this->responseType->setPrivateKey($this->privateKey);

        return $this->responseType;
    }
}
```

And a custom PassportServiceProvider like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\TokenServer;

class PassportServiceProvider extends \Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Make the authorization service instance.
     *
     * @return AuthorizationServer
     */
    public function makeAuthorizationServer()
    {
        return new TokenServer(
            $this->app->make(\Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ClientRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(\Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessTokenRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(\Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ScopeRepository::class),
            'file://'.storage_path('oauth-private.key'),
            'file://'.storage_path('oauth-public.key')
        );
    }

}
```

And then make the following change in your config/app.php file:

```
/*
 * Package Service Providers...
 * We extend the packaged PassportServiceProvider with our own customization
 */

// Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```