# Customising token response Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working on an API at the moment and have hit a brick wall. I am using Passport with the 'Password' grant type.

I want to return the user information with the access tokens, however, I am not sure how to.

Which class could I implement, edit or extend to get this?.

I would like this to be returned:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": "lalalalalal",
    "refresh_token": "lalalallala",
    "user": {
        "username": "a username",
        "user_type": "admin"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Laravel Passport BearerTokenResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743020/custom-laravel-passport-bearertokenresponse)

Answer (score 27):

The instructions on how to do this are hinted in the [`BearerTokenResponse`](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/2a16dbeb7f83135db25a1a2b416f6696e5906f5a/src/ResponseTypes/BearerTokenResponse.php#L67) class (part of the league/oauth2-server package).

Tested on Laravel 5.7.

**1. Extend the `BearerTokenResponse` class, add the extra params you need in the response**.

```
namespace App\Auth;

use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\AccessTokenEntityInterface;

class BearerTokenResponse extends \League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse
{
    /**
     * Add custom fields to your Bearer Token response here, then override
     * AuthorizationServer::getResponseType() to pull in your version of
     * this class rather than the default.
     *
     * @param AccessTokenEntityInterface $accessToken
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getExtraParams(AccessTokenEntityInterface $accessToken): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->accessToken->getUserIdentifier(),
        ];
    }
}
```

**2. Create your own `PassportServiceProvider` class and override the `makeAuthorizationServer()` method in order to pass in your own `BearerTokenResponse` class.**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\BearerTokenResponse;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge;
use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;

class PassportServiceProvider extends \Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Make the authorization service instance.
     *
     * @return \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer
     */
    public function makeAuthorizationServer()
    {
        return new AuthorizationServer(
            $this->app->make(Bridge\ClientRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(Bridge\AccessTokenRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(Bridge\ScopeRepository::class),
            $this->makeCryptKey('private'),
            app('encrypter')->getKey(),
            new BearerTokenResponse() // <-- The class you created above
        );
    }
}
```

**3. Add your provider to the providers array in `config/app.php`**

```
    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

**4. Exclude the passport package from laravel auto-discovery in `composer.json`**

This stops the default `PassportServiceProvider` class from being loaded.

```
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/passport"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Then run `composer install`.

Comment: Hi! Adding`"dont-discover"` option for all `laravel/passport` won't cause issues with composer not auto-loading other needed classes for Passport???

Comment: Also, instead of `composer install`, `composer dump-autoload` wouldn't be more appropriated?

Comment: It seems it worked for me. Apparently it's the easiest way of doing this at the moment.

Comment: I would say, this is a clean solution. I tested in laravel 5.8 and it is working.

Comment: tested in Laravel 9.4 and it's still working :-)

Comment: Works with Laravel 8.x

Answer (score 12):

Two steps.

**1**. **Add a new route in your routes file.**

```
// routes/api.php

Route::post('oauth/token', 'AuthController@auth');
```

Keep in mind this will change the route for getting the token from `/oauth/token` to `/api/oauth/token`.

**2**. **Add the controller method.**

```
<?php
// app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;

class AuthController extends AccessTokenController
{
    public function auth(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
            $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);
            $token = $tokenResponse->getContent();

            // $tokenInfo will contain the usual Laravel Passort token response.
            $tokenInfo = json_decode($token, true);

            // Then we just add the user to the response before returning it.
            $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];
            $user = User::whereEmail($username)->first();
            $tokenInfo = collect($tokenInfo);
            $tokenInfo->put('user', $user);

            return $tokenInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should result in an invalid token signature?

Answer (score 3):

Im using [Multi-Auth with passport](https://github.com/sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth), so the previous answers didn't help me.

After hours of "googling" I found this answer [(after-) middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412235/return-the-access-token-and-the-user-when-authenticating-using-passport-and-lara).

My middleware basically gets the result of Passport auth, checks if there is an Bearer inside and append more data to the content.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AppendTokenResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $response =  $next($request);

        $content = json_decode($response->content(), true);

        if (!empty($content['access_token'])) {

            $content['moredata'] = 'some data';

            $response->setContent($content);

        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Now put the new Middleware in $routemiddleware at App/Http/Kernel.php

```
 /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        'multiauth' => \SMartins\PassportMultiauth\Http\Middleware\MultiAuthenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'oauth.providers' => \SMartins\PassportMultiauth\Http\Middleware\AddCustomProvider::class,
        'append_auth' =>\App\Http\Middleware\AppendTokenResponse::class,

    ];
```

Then just register this middleware to Passport Routes in Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

With Multiauth:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['oauth.providers','append_auth']], function () {
    Passport::routes(function ($router) {
        return $router->forAccessTokens();
    });
});
```

I believe regular passport should be (not tested):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['append_auth']], function () {
    Passport::routes();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another better answer from the web

Custom Laravel Passport BearerTokenResponse

https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d

Comment: Although this answer has received more upvotes than any other as of 25 September 2018, it is not considered a high quality answer as it is link-only.

Answer (score 2):

To add custom claims to your Passport token, here is a gist using Passport 8 with Laravel 6

https://gist.github.com/onamfc/0422da15743918e653888441ba6226ca