# Return the access token and the user when authenticating using Passport and Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am creating an API using Laravel 5.4 and Passport. 
The API authorization is done using Password grant type.

Below is a sample request:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
  'form_params' => [
     'grant_type' => 'password',
     'client_id' => 'client-id',
     'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
     'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
     'password' => 'my-password',
     'scope' => '',
   ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

This will send a POST request to '/oauth/token' with the following response:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3155673600,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJK...",
  "refresh_token": "LbxXGlD2s..."
}
```

What I want is to get a response including the authenticated user as shown below:

```
[
  data:{
     name: Jhon,
     email: jhon@example.com,
     address: ASDF Street no.23
  },
  token{
     "token_type": "Bearer",
     "expires_in": 3155673600,
     "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJK...",
     "refresh_token": "LbxXGlD2s..."
  }
]
```

What I already did was alter the PasswordGrant file at line 65

```
vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Grant/PasswordGrant.php

$responseType->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$responseType->setRefreshToken($refreshToken);
return $responseType;
```

I hope someone can help me, and tell me how to resolve this,
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an [(after-) middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware) that takes the original response and transforms it to be the way you want it to be. But be aware that all other Passport middleware (`CheckClientCredentials`, `CheckScopes`, `CreateFreshApiToken`, etc...) probably depends on that specific format and will have to be adapted as well.